# Cordova contacts plugin on ionic2 not working

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, contacts, ionic2

I have installed contacs cordova plugin on my ionic2 platform with the command

`sudo ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts`

Now I can see the plugin sub directory in the plugin dir of my app.
On visual studio code I can see the sources and use the objects but I have two issues:

- when I run the app with 'ionic serve' command, I can see error in the console of the browser cause the constructor of ContactFindOptions is missing. The reason can be that in the browser I can see 'contacts.js' but I cannot see 'contacts.d.js' (where the ContactFindOptions should be defined)
- I removed every reference to ContactFindOptions in my code, using a simple object instead, and now the browser works as expected (throws a 'cordova_not_availabe' exception). So I uploaded the app on Ionic View and got another error on my phone (android): "plugin_not_installed".

How can I check if something is missing in the plugin installation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Plugins do not work in Browsers, please try in emulator or deivce.

Comment: Yeah, plugins don't work with ionic view either, but you can use this [chrome extension](https://github.com/pbernasconi/chrome-cordova) to mock some cordova plugins in the browser (including Contacts)

Answer (score 0):

After adding the plugin, have you also added a definition for your plugin in your typings?

In one or a file.d.ts you need the definition for the plugin, something like

```
interface Navigator {
   contacts: ContactsPlugin;
}

interface ContactsPlugin {
    create(options:any);
    find(fields:any, onSuccess:any, onError:any, options:any);
    pickContact(contactSuccess:any, contactError:any);
}
```

P.S.: Of course for real application develop that declaration with more details